# magento 2 css not loading

Tags: magento2, css

I added custom css in Magento 2 but frontend it shows `404 not found`

**`Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml`**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/mycss.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
          <referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" display="false" />
          <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" display="false" />
          <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
            <container label="Top Slideshow Container" name="page.top.slideshow" as="topslideshow" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="slideshow-wrapper" before="-" />
        </referenceContainer>     
      </body>
</page>
```

I added css in this location **`Magento_Theme/web/css/mycss.css`** But frontend it shows **`404`**

Comment: Did you deploy static content ?

Comment: Yes i did that and reindex clear cache delete cache folder di:compile command. But no luck

Comment: Can  you paste whole code here ?

Comment: this is my full code

Comment: What is full directory structure for Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml ?

Comment: Please check answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add css file as

**web/css/mycss.css**

instead of

**Magento_Theme/web/css/mycss.css**

Then deploy the content.

Comment: Great. I'm glad it helped you.

Comment: Hey this css calling only home page how to call all page

Comment: use default.xml file instead of cms_index_index.xml